# increment variable according to numbers of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

javascript:

```
var counter = 0;
var totalItems = 8;
var restItems = $num-totalItems;
if (restItems==22) {
    $('#next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        counter++;
        updatestatus();     
    });
}     

function updatestatus() {   
    totalItems = totalItems + 8 * counter;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type = "button" id="next" value="click me">
```

what I want is that before I click the button, the totoalItems is equal to 8, and each time when I click it, the totoal item is added by 8, but at the moment that bit of code dosen't work and give me a very large number, any one could help me figure it out, thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need to mulitply by 8 if you're just adding 8 each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var counter = 0;
var totalItems = 8;
var restItems = $num - totalItems;

if (restItems == 22) {
    $('#next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        updatestatus();
    });
}

function updatestatus() {
    totalItems = totalItems + 8 * counter;
}
```

With this code, every time you run `updatestatus()`, it increments `totalItems` by its own value *and* `8 * counter`. You don't need to increment it:

```
function updatestatus() {
    totalItems = 8 + 8 * counter;
}
```

But ideally, I'd just simplify the code:

```
var counter = 0;
var totalItems = 8;
var restItems = $num - totalItems;

$('#next').click(function(e) {
    if (restItems == 22) {
        e.preventDefault();
        totalItems += 8;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you multiplying by the counter?

```
totalItems = totalItems + 8;
```

Comment: Either that, or `totalItems = 8 * counter`